# Does elasticsearch/lucene impose memory overhead for missing values in fieldcache?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

This question is for Elasticsearch primarily, but I believe the answer will be based on underlying Lucene semantics.

I'm contemplating using multiple types in the same index. A lot of fields will be sortable and a lot of fields will only be used by one particular type. I.e: fields will be sparse, say 10% coverage on average.

Since sorting keeps values for all docs in memory (regardess of type) , I'd like to know if there's any memory overhead with regards to missing fieldvalues (the ~90% in my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recent blog post on the official Elasticsearch blog titled ["Index vs Type"](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type), the author tackles a common problematic when it comes to choosing whether one wants to model his data using several indices or several types.

One fact is that Lucene indices don't like sparsity. As a result, the author says that

> Fields that exist in one type will also consume resources for documents of types where this field does not exist. [...] And the issue is even worse with doc values: for speed reasons, doc values often reserve a fixed amount of disk space for every document, so that values can be addressed efficiently.

There is a [Lucene issue](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6863) that aims at improving this situation, which has been fixed in 5.4 and will be available in Elasticsearch v2.2. Even then, the author advises to still model your data in a way to limits sparsity as much as possible.